# Настройка WSL с Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Работа через общий vpn OpenVPN

Tags: windows, ubuntu, openvpn, wsl

Установил Ubuntu 20.04 LTS на Windows 10 через wsl.
Всё корректно работает, но возникает проблема настройки маршрутизации трафика.

На компьютере работаю через рабочий vpn с доступом до офисной инфраструктуры.
Для доступа используется OpenVPN с конфигурацией подключения, прописанной в ovpn файле.
Нужно чтобы и через Ubuntu мог обращаться к рабочим ресурсам.

Подскажите, как настроить работу так, чтобы со своего компьютера мог обращаться к офисным ресурсам, как с самой windows машины, так и с виртуальной в wsl.

Заранее спасибо

Comment: достаточно на винде настроить твой впн в всл он тоже будет работать.

Comment: Yakow, я потому и задаю вопрос, что не работает)

Comment: Если опенвпн у тебя создает сетевой интерфейс в винде, то работает, если не создает, тогда надо клиента ставить на линукс внутри всл.

Comment: проверял сейчас у меня AnyConnect, не опенвпн, но пинги из убунты в всл уходят через адаптер на винде.

Comment: sudo apt install net-tools и смотри после поднятия соединения видно ли в всл в ifconfig адрес впна?